# How to declare an enum properly Java

Tags: java, enums

I tried to declare an `enum` for the first time in Java, as following:

```
public enum Atom_const{
    public final float HIDROGEN_RADIUS=.1f;
    public final float CARBON_RADIUS=.28f;
}
```

Eclipse gives me an error `"Syntax error on token "{", ; expected"`, however I have never seen syntaxes like "{;" before, neither have I seen this in `enum` examples. So what is the proper way to declare an `enum`?

I did look on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html but no ; is after the {. I suspect this happens because I make the assignments, but I'm not sure of that.

Comment: Did you try asking google?

Comment: This should tell you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: @baraky very soon when someone asks google, he might see this page :)

Comment: duffymo's comment is what you get when you google "how to declare an enum in java" btw.

Comment: I did look on the documentation, and no ; is after the {

Comment: @rajesh - but not for long ... hopefully :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're half way between declaring an enum and declaring some constant fields. I suspect you want something like:

```
public enum Element {
    HYDROGEN(.1f),
    CARBON(.28f);

    private final float radius;

    private Element(float radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public float getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
}
```

Comment: But will java know that my HYDROGEN and CARBON are final floats?

Comment: @BujancaMihai They aren't. They are `enum`s of type Element, that's the entire point. You can get a radius from them with getRadius.

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to declare a enum with floating point numbers in Java you should do it like this:

```
public enum AtomRadius {
    HYDROGEN(.1f),
    CARBON(.28f);

    private final float radius;

    private AtomRadius(float radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Example of how to use your constant
    AtomRadius atom = AtomRadius.HYDROGEN;
    System.out.println(atom.radius);
}
```

For more info check: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum Atom_const {
    HYDROGEN(.1f),
    CARBON(.28f);

    private float radius;

    private Atom_const(float radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public float getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to declare `public final float`

```
 enum Atom_const{   
   HYDROGEN_RADIUS(.1f),
   CARBON_RADIUS(.28f);}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it helped you. If you need more help you are welcome. Please ask.